# Perl search replace with negative lookahead

Tags: regex, perl, bash

This one is driving me crazy.  Trying to do a command-line search/replace with perl. Essentially I want to strip out all file paths that don't end in XLS(X), but they have to start with the string NATIVE.  Thanks in advance!

### Command

```
cat test.txt | perl -ne 's/"(?!NATIVE[^"]+XLSX?)"/""/g; print;'
```

### test.txt

```
"Blah","NATIVE/001/FOO.XLS","Blah"
"Blah","NATIVE/001/BAR.XLSX","Blah"
"Blah","NATIVE/001/FOO.DOC","Blah"
"Blah","NATIVE/001/FOO.PPT","Blah"
"Blah","NATIVE/001/FOO.PPTX","Blah"
"Blah","NATIVE/001/FOO.PNG","Blah"
```

### Expected Output

```
"Blah","NATIVE/001/FOO.XLS","Blah"
"Blah","NATIVE/001/BAR.XLSX","Blah"
"Blah","","Blah"
"Blah","","Blah"
"Blah","","Blah"
"Blah","","Blah"
```

### Actual Output

```
"Blah","NATIVE/001/FOO.XLS","Blah"
"Blah","NATIVE/001/BAR.XLSX","Blah"
"Blah","NATIVE/001/FOO.DOC","Blah"
"Blah","NATIVE/001/FOO.PPT","Blah"
"Blah","NATIVE/001/FOO.PPTX","Blah"
"Blah","NATIVE/001/FOO.PNG","Blah"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this pattern with lookbehinds:

```
cat test.txt | perl -ne 's/"NATIVE\/[^"]+(?<!\.XLS)(?<!\.XLSX)"/""/g; print;'
```

or

```
cat test.txt | perl -ne 's/"NATIVE\/[^"]++(?<!\.XLS)(?<!\.XLSX)/"/g; print;'
```

You need to be sure that the lookbehinds start just before the closing quote. To do that, you have two ways: writing the closing quote or using a possessive quantifier.

Comment: There it is!  Looks like the [^"]+ captured everything to the end of the field and my lookAHEAD wasn't matching because of it.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -pe 's/"NATIVE[^"]+(?<!\.XLSX)(?<!\.XLS)"/""/g;' test.txt
```

Basically, use a negative lookbehind assertion.  And because they can't be variable length, just use two.

Note, if assertions are too challenging sometimes, you can break up your logic using the /e modifier.  The following also would work and simply does the replacement conditionally in two steps:

```
perl -pe 's/"\K(NATIVE[^"]+)/$1 =~ m{XLSX?$} ? $1 : ""/eg;' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a **Negative Lookbehind** here instead.

```
cat test.txt | perl -ne 's/"NATIVE[^"]+(?<!\.XLS|XLSX)"/""/g; print;'
```

You could also use Lookahead and Lookbehind for the quotes also.

```
cat test.txt | perl -ne 's/(?<=")NATIVE[^"]+(?<!\.XLS|XLSX)(?=")//g; print;'
```

Output

```
"Blah","NATIVE/001/FOO.XLS","Blah"
"Blah","NATIVE/001/BAR.XLSX","Blah"
"Blah","","Blah"
"Blah","","Blah"
"Blah","","Blah"
"Blah","","Blah"
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my attempt pattern `(?<=")NATIVE[^.]*\.(?!\XLSX?")[^"]+`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hW8nC6)

Answer (score 0):

No need for lookbehind:

`cat test.txt | perl -ne 's/"NATIVE(?![^"]+XLSX?")[^"]*"/""/g; print;'`